# Azure functions not active after publish

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am playing around with azure functions using VS code and core tools.

I initialized [this](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/queue-trigger-blob-in-out-binding) example from github

- Added remote storage account and Funcitons App in the cloud console
- Puttet the connection details in the local.settings.json
- Checked the namings in the functions.json so it matches my setup

When running locally with `func start` it works like charm.

When i do `func azure functionapp publish QueueTrigger` it deploys and the app is popping up in the cloud console. 
But: Its not doing anything. No action. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out after about 3 hours of searching.

`func azure functionapp publish Queue2Table --publish-local-settings` is needed

its not so well described in the docs but finally mentioned in the options `[here][1]`